# Follow organization on github

Tags: github

Is there any workaround to follow organization in github?
The old trick

```
$.post("https://github.com/users/follow?target=organizationName");
```

doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me like there is no workaround.

http://github.com does not currently have follow buttons for organizations. I'm assuming that following an organization was a bug that has been recently fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported now (March 2022, 8 years later).

> ### [Following organizations](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-03-23-following-organizations/)
>
> You can now follow organizations just like you can already follow users and keep up to date with the latest activity related to the organizations you follow in the new "For you" feed.
>
> Following organizations is available to anyone on GitHub as a public beta today.
>
> Learn more about the new "**[For you](https://docs.github.com/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-user-account-settings/about-your-personal-dashboard#for-you-feed)**" feed and **[how to follow organizations](https://docs.github.com/get-started/exploring-projects-on-github/following-organizations)**.

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-17413/images/help/profile/organization-profile-following.png]

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-70499/images/help/profile/user-profile-following.png]